# How to filter date to get the film release date in sparql using regex

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, querying

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?releaseDate
WHERE {
   ?film rdf:type db:Film;
   foaf:name ?title.
   ?film  dbp:releaseDate ?releaseDate.     
   FILTER regex(?releaseDate, "2016", "i").
}
```

Getting the release date but only two i am not sure about querying . since i am new to this.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do. 
Could you extend your question with an example and the expected output?

Comment: the query is correct as well as the result. There is no more data mathing the query, that's all. In your previous question you used `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate`, now for whatever reason you decided to use`http://dbpedia.org/property/releaseDate` which leads to less data.

Comment: The correct filter has to convert the literal to a string first, i.e. `FILTER regex(str(?releaseDate), "2016", "i").` And then use `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/releaseDate`. The query has to be `SELECT ?releaseDate
WHERE {?film rdf:type db:Film;foaf:name ?title.?film  db:releaseDate ?releaseDate.FILTER regex(str(?releaseDate), "2016", "i")
}`

Comment: the better query using date operations instead of regex: `SELECT ?releaseDate
WHERE {
?film rdf:type db:Film;
foaf:name ?title.
?film  db:releaseDate ?releaseDate.     
FILTER (year(?releaseDate) = 2016)
}`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks alot for your help. it works like a charm

Comment: By the way, which DBpedia endpoint are you using?

Comment: @AKSW by using the query below :
SELECT ?title ?releaseDate (GROUP_CONCAT(?ArtistName ; separator=",") as ?artists) 
WHERE 
{

?film rdf:type db:Film;
foaf:name ?title.

?film db:releaseDate ?releaseDate.
FILTER regex(str(?releaseDate), "2016", "i")

?film dbp:starring ?ArtistName .
 }

I am getting the duplicate values could you please help with this.

Comment: @AKSW i think its getting value from both film and filmfestival, is there a way we can get only from film?

Comment: it's because some films have multiple release dates in the dataset. And again, you used `dbp:` which leads to way less result.

Comment: `SELECT ?film ?title (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?releaseDate ; separator=",") as ?releaseDates) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?ArtistName ; separator=",") as ?artists) WHERE {
 ?film rdf:type db:Film; 
foaf:name ?title. filter(lang(?title) = 'en')
?film db:releaseDate ?releaseDate. 
FILTER regex(str(?releaseDate), "2016", "i") 
?film db:starring ?ArtistName . 
} 
group by ?film ?title
order by ?title`

Comment: @ASKW THanks but is there a way if i input the query ?class rdf:type owl:Class.
    FILTER regex(?class, "film", "i" ).
can i get only film instead of getting film festival too.

Comment: I don't see why you think you're getting filmfestival. Your query says `?film rdf:type db:Film` so at least in DBpedia this are just films. and your regex would also match *"film festival"* given that *"film"* is a substring of it. which one of the result would be a film festival in your opinion?

Comment: Improved formatting